# Is there a SSHD "Match" Argument for "If user doesn't use pubkey/SSH key auth, do x"?

Tags: linux, ssh, authentication, public-key

Is it possible to create a Match argument for when a SSH connection doesn't use a public key for authentication (such as when they use a password instead)? Ideally, I want to run a certain ForceCommand when users aren't authenticating via SSH/Public Key. Something like this in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file:

```
Match "Pubkeyauthentication No"* (*This is what I'm looking to replace with an actual filter)
  ForceCommand x
```

Is what I'm looking for possible? If not in the above way, then in some other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know if this kind of possibility exists, on the other hand you can force connection **only** by a public/private keys, and refuse login/passwd

in /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

**Edit:** After some thought ...
You should be able to meet your need *(or approach it)*, by analyzing the connection logs *(with a script)*, depending on the "verbose" mode you should have this information, and therefore trigger, a console message, an email or whatever.
it's a track

Comment: I knew this variable existed, but I had too much tunnel vision into the 'Match' variable that I forgot it can be disabled altogether. Thank you, that effectively takes care of things, although something like my question describes would eventually be nice. Using a custom script sounds scary for something as integral as SSHD.